# concatenate rows from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a select statement which is something like this

```
select col1 from table1 where cond1=true
```

This returns results like

```
col1
_____
5
5
6
3
```

but I want to change it to return me

```
5-5-6-3
```

Is this possible? If so how? Please let me know how to do this. Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: This seems an almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-groupconcat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005 (almost since the answers are the same, not the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably could, but why not do this in the application? I don't know what language you're using, but you could do something like this after you get the result of the query (pseudocode):

```
result = result.join('-')
```

Comment: s. But i want to do it in SQL query for some specific reason.

Answer (score 3):

This does exactly what you want:

```
declare @ret varchar(500)
set @ret=''
select @ret = @ret + col1 + '-' from test

select substring(@ret, 1, len(@ret)-1)
```

NOTE: if your col1 is *int* then I think you will have to use *convert* or *cast* to make it *varchar*.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html

```
SELECT my_column AS [text()]
FROM   my_table
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Is GROUP_CONCAT available in MS SQL Server?  What I find by Googling suggests it is not available.

Comment: No, GROUP_CONCAT is not available in MS SQL Server, but the above solution is MS SQL's equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Microsoft SQL Server, you should be able to do it with the REPLACE command.

```
SELECT col1,
       dynamic_text = REPLACE( 
                ( 
                    SELECT 
                        DISTINCT phone_col2 AS [data()] 
                    FROM 
                        table2
                    WHERE 
                        condition 
                    FOR XML PATH ('') 
                ), '', '-')

 FROM table1
WHERE condition
```

Something like that would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do this in front end, for a large number of rows this will be quite slow. SQL Server is extremely slow sting concatenation. You could create a .net function that takes the table and returns the string, that way you can ensure speed.

If there is no performance worry, like its a one time thing etc go with the other solutions above as those are handled in sql

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
  --Sample Data
DECLARE @Test TABLE
    (
    Col1 int 
    )

INSERT @Test
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 5

--The query
SELECT          SUBSTRING(
                (
                SELECT          '-' + CAST(Col1 AS varchar(10))
                FROM            @Test
                ORDER BY        Col1
                FOR XML PATH    ('')
                ), 2, 2000) AS MyJoinedColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @Test table (rowid int identity(1,1) primary key, col1 int not null)
insert into @test Values (5)
insert into @test Values (5)
insert into @test Values (6)
insert into @test Values (3)


declare @value varchar(500)
set @value=NULL
select @value = COALESCE(@Value+'-'+CONVERT(varchar,col1),convert(varchar,col1)) from @Test

print @value
```

Answer (score 0):

Under MySQL you can do that easily

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR '-') from table1 where cond1=true
```